# Should Unit Test data be simplified or realistic?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Say I want to write a unit test for the following Python function:

```
def multiply(dict_1, dict_2):
    result = {}
    for (key_1, key_2) in dict_1:
        result[(key_1, key_2)] = dict_1[(key_1, key_2)] * dict_2[key_2]
    return result
```

`dict_1` and `dict_2` are outputs from other functions. They're not long, but they look kinda complex:

```
dict_1 = {
        ('Nietzsche', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('1.49177787'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'RM'): Decimal('10971.22182930'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'LS'): Decimal('4.44771349'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'NCDU'): Decimal('5.14671343'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'SUDO'): Decimal('9.49572673'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PS'): Decimal('0.57328494'),
        ('Hegel', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'SUDO'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'PS'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'LS'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'PKILL'): Decimal('0E-8')
    }
dict_2 = {
        'USR1': Decimal('6357.48'),
        'PKILL': Decimal('307.277'),
        'RM': Decimal('88.232'),
        'LS': Decimal('71.1787'),
        'NCDU': Decimal('0.0389333'),
        'SUDO': Decimal('199.979'),
        'PS': Decimal('307.277')
    }
```

The output of this function for these specific parameters also looks kinda complex:

```
{
    ('Nietzsche', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-10'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('458.38902855999'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'RM'): Decimal('968012.84444279760'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'LS'): Decimal('316.582464190663'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0.200378537984219'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'SUDO'): Decimal('1898.94593573867'),
    ('Nietzsche', 'PS'): Decimal('176.15727650838'),
    ('Hegel', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-10'),
    ('Marx', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0E-15'),
    ('Marx', 'SUDO'): Decimal('0E-11'),
    ('Marx', 'PS'): Decimal('0E-11'),
    ('Marx', 'LS'): Decimal('0E-12'),
    ('Marx', 'PKILL'): Decimal('0E-11')
}
```

So I'm faced with two options for the unit test. Number one is to have realistic data by copy-pasting everything:

```
def test_multiply_1(self):
    dict_1 = {
        ('Nietzsche', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('1.49177787'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'RM'): Decimal('10971.22182930'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'LS'): Decimal('4.44771349'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'NCDU'): Decimal('5.14671343'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'SUDO'): Decimal('9.49572673'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PS'): Decimal('0.57328494'),
        ('Hegel', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'SUDO'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'PS'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'LS'): Decimal('0E-8'),
        ('Marx', 'PKILL'): Decimal('0E-8')
    }
    dict_2 = {
        'USR1': Decimal('6357.48'),
        'PKILL': Decimal('307.277'),
        'RM': Decimal('88.232'),
        'LS': Decimal('71.1787'),
        'NCDU': Decimal('0.0389333'),
        'SUDO': Decimal('199.979'),
        'PS': Decimal('307.277')
    }
    expected = {
        ('Nietzsche', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-10'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('458.38902855999'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'RM'): Decimal('968012.84444279760'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'LS'): Decimal('316.582464190663'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0.200378537984219'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'SUDO'): Decimal('1898.94593573867'),
        ('Nietzsche', 'PS'): Decimal('176.15727650838'),
        ('Hegel', 'USR1'): Decimal('0E-10'),
        ('Marx', 'NCDU'): Decimal('0E-15'),
        ('Marx', 'SUDO'): Decimal('0E-11'),
        ('Marx', 'PS'): Decimal('0E-11'),
        ('Marx', 'LS'): Decimal('0E-12'),
        ('Marx', 'PKILL'): Decimal('0E-11')
    }
    actual = multiply(dict_1, dict_2)
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

Number two is to simplify using dummy data:

```
def test_multiply_1(self):
    dict_1 = { ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('1.49177787') }
    dict_2 = { 'PKILL': Decimal('307.277') }
    actual = multiply(dict_1, dict_2)
    expected = { ('Nietzsche', 'PKILL'): Decimal('458.38902855999') }
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

Number two is way more readable, but number one is more realistic. Which one is preferred and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would favor the simplified unit test. If you decide to change the functionality of this code, it'll be much easier to update the simplified unit test rather than the long and complex one.

Aside from that, the purpose of unit tests is to check whether small components of code work at their base level for realistic expected inputs, reduced to the smallest amount of complexity. If you find that the unit test to check the base functionality is too complex, you may want to split up the function into smaller components in itself. In this case, I think your functionality is straightforward enough and you would benefit more from the simple unit test than the complex one. However, this question is definitely opinion-based.

Comment: "[T]he purpose of unit tests is to check whether...code work[s]...for trivial inputs" perhaps overstates the word *trivial*. A unit test should ensure that the code under test works for any input it might realistically be passed. That should include throwing responsible errors for nonsensical code, in the most ideal case.